# Residue theorem pole

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How do I find poles of this function?
$$f(z) = \frac{1-\cos z}{z^4 +z^3}$$

I am unable to identify zero pole order of $f(z)$ as it includes trigonometric functions and I'm new to this concept. Please help me out to identify the pole order.

Answer (score 0):

Replace cos(z) with its expression as a power series:'
$cos(z)= 1+ z^2/2+ z^4/4!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$
so $1- cos(z)= -z^2/2- z^4/4!-\cdot\cdot\cdot$.

$\frac{1- cos(z)}{z^4+ z^3}= -\frac{z^2/2+ z^4/4!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot}{z^2(z^2+ z)}$
$=-\frac{1/2+ z^2/4!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot}{z^2+z}$

Answer (score 0):

The residue of $f(z)$ at $a$ is $\lim_\limits{z\to a} f(z)(z-a)$

If you have a simple pole, i.e. $f(z) = \frac {g(z)}{z-a}$ and $g(z)$ is analytic at $a$ then the residue at $a$ is $g(a).$  If you have a second order pole, $f(z) = \frac {g(z)}{(z-a)^2}$ and $g(a) = 0,$  then the residue is $g'(a).$  Which is analogous to applying L'Hoptial's rule in Calc I.

And you can keep applying higher order derivatives as necessary.

It shouldn't really matter what sort of function you have in the numerator.

In some cases it is easier to expand the function as a Laurent series.  Which is similar to a Taylor series.

That is $f(z) = \cdots \frac {c_{-2}}{(z-a)^2} + \frac {c_{-1}}{z-a} + c_0 + c_1(z-a) + \cdots$

And the residue is the $c_{-1}$ coefficient.

What do we have here?

$f(z) = \frac {1-\cos z}{z^3(z+1)}$

The function fails to be analytic at $z = -1$ and $z = 0$

The residue at $z = -1:$

$\lim_\limits{z\to -1} \frac {1-\cos z}{z^3} = \cos 1 - 1$

The residue at $z = 0:$

$\lim_\limits{z\to 0} \frac {1-\cos z}{z^2(z+1)} = \frac {d^2z}{dz^2} \frac {1-\cos z}{z+1}$

Or we could expand the numerator as a Taylor series.

$\lim_\limits{z\to 0} \frac {\frac {z^2}{2} - \frac {z^4}{4!} + \cdots}{z^2(z+1)}$

Cancel the $z^2$ terms with the denominator.

$\lim_\limits{z\to 0} \frac {\frac {1}{2} - \frac {z^2}{4!} + \cdots}{(z+1)}$

And consider the limit as $z$ approaches $0$